# Custom WPF Control using Expression Effect dll

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have set up the dependency properties:

```
   Public Shared ReadOnly SourceImageColor00Property As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SourceImageColor00", GetType(ColorToneEffect), GetType(OPCWPFImageColor))
```

And my property look lie this:

```
      <Description("Image Color to display"), _
Category("Color Properties")> _
Public Property SourceImageColor00() As ColorToneEffect
    Get
        Return DirectCast(Me.GetValue(SourceImageColor00Property), ColorToneEffect)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ColorToneEffect)
        Me.SetValue(SourceImageColor00Property, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

The problem is that when I have an instance of the control in design mode the property name is displayed as "Color Tone" instead of "SourceImageColor00".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried <DisplayName("Color Tone")> attribute?

Comment: Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an DisplayName attribute for property:

```
<Description("Image Color to display"), _
Category("Color Properties"), _
DisplayName("Color Tone")> _
Public Property SourceImageColor00() As ColorToneEffect
    Get
        Return DirectCast(Me.GetValue(SourceImageColor00Property), ColorToneEffect)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ColorToneEffect)
        Me.SetValue(SourceImageColor00Property, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx